# HTML to Text Conversion

Tags: html

Internet Explorer has an option to save a web page as a text file, with all the tags removed. I need a way to batch process that stuff for a project at work. Or there any command line utilities or libraries that can do the same thing for me? COM-interop with IE(not my first choice!)? It doesn't have to format exactly like IE, just give me plain text.

Answer (score 1):

There are many programs that do this.  Some are called html2text.  There's [this one](http://www.mbayer.de/html2text/files.shtml) (which isn't available available natively for Windows, but compiles under Cygwin), and [another](http://www.xs4all.nl/~kmachine/html2txt.htm) that is for Win32.

Answer (score 0):

I've once seen a script that used `lynx` for rendering HTML to plain text for automatic generation of a plain text mail from HTML. Not my first choice as well, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in C# using the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/):

```
var doc = new HtmlWeb.Load(url);
File.WriteAllText(path, doc.DocumentElement.InnerText);
```